# Mysql / Eloquent / Laravel aggregate data returned by query in usable form for view

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent, aggregate

I have this situation:

```
$x = user->waist_id;
$y = user->pants_size_id;


 $sizes = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT model_id, 
   pants_sizes.id AS size_id, 
   Count(pants_sizes.id) AS Total FROM   `pants_sizes` 
   INNER JOIN `owned_items` 
           ON `pants_sizes`.`id` = `owned_items`.`model_size_id` 
   INNER JOIN `owned_item_user` 
           ON `owned_items`.`id` = `owned_item_user`.`owned_item_id` 
   INNER JOIN `users` 
           ON `users`.`id` = `owned_item_user`.`user_id` WHERE  `waist_id` = $x 
   AND `pants_size_id` = $y 
   AND `owned_items`.`model_id` IN ( 218, 219 ) GROUP  BY `model_id`, 
      `pants_sizes`.`id` "))

return $sizes;
```

with this query I am joining some tables to get the sizes of a specific pants model owned by users based on same attributes (example waist and pants_size).

this returns the data in this form:

```
[
      {
      "model_id": 218,
      "size_id": 4,
      "Total": 3
      },
      {
      "model_id": 218,
      "size_id": 5,
      "Total": 7
      },
      {
      "model_id": 219,
      "size_id": 4,
      "Total": 3
      },
      {
      "model_id": 219,
      "size_id": 5,
      "Total": 7
      }
]
```

what I need is the data to be returned like this instead:

```
[
      {
      "model_id": 218,
      "size_id": 4,
      "Total_size_id_4": 3
      "size_id": 5,
      "Total_size_id_5": 7
      "Total": 10

      },
      "model_id": 219,
      "size_id": 4,
      "Total_size_id_4": 3
      "size_id": 5,
      "Total_size_id_5": 7
      "Total": 10
      },

]
```

or in a way that I can use to produce statistics in the view, example:

```
 [
      {
      "model_id": 218,
      "4": "30%",
      "5": "70%",
      "Total": 10

      },
      "model_id": 219,
      "4": "30%",
      "5": "70%",
      "Total": 10
      },

]
```

"model 218 is owned by 10 users, 30% has size 4 and 70% has size 5"

Can this be done modifying the above query? with some group concat and sum stuff maybe?